# Why is dogs saliva considered Haram in Islam?

Tags: fiqh, dogs, pets

Is there a prohibition to take care of dogs in the rule in Islam, because I just to know it is haram if exposed to saliva alone?

Comment: If the dog is *yours*, the dog's purpose may be important here. Pet? Hunting? Guard? If the dog is simply in your care (say, as a veterinarian) it may be different. It might be useful to add more context.

Comment: According to Shia, it is not forbidden but only discouraged as a pet, it is unclean and put you in trouble when you need to be clean, for example for praying and etc., also your dishes may become unclean and ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is only Haram to have a dog if it is for being a pet, other than that the dog is ok.

> مَنِ اتَّخَذَ كَلْبًا إِلاَّ كَلْبَ مَاشِيَةٍ أَوْ صَيْدٍ أَوْ زَرْعٍ
> انْتَقَصَ مِنْ أَجْرِهِ كُلَّ يَوْمٍ قِيرَاطٌ
>
> That the Messenger of Allah () said: "Whoever acquires a dog - with
> the exception of a dog to guard livestock, a hunting dog, or a farm
> dog - each day a Qirat is deducted from his reward.
>
> [Abi Dawood](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/17/1)

But it is also good to take care of animals, and dogs are animals and there is a reward for taking care of animals.

> Yahya related to me from Malik from Sumayy, the mawla of Abu Bakr from
> Abu Salih as-Samman from Abu Hurayra that the Messenger of Allah, may
> Allah bless him and grant him peace, said, "A man was walking on a
> road when he became very thirsty. He found a well and went into it and
> drank and came out. There was a dog panting and eating earth out of
> thirst. The man said, 'This dog has become as thirsty as I was.' He
> went down into the well and filled his shoe and then held it in his
> mouth until he climbed out and gave the dog water to drink. Allah
> thanked him for it and forgave him." They said, "Messenger of Allah,
> do we have a reward for taking care of beasts?" He said, "There is a
> reward for every one with a moist liver."

[Muwatta' Malik](http://sunnah.com/urn/417560)

Comment: "Each day a Qirat is deducted from his reward", what is Qirat?

Comment: @mezhang it is a measure, how much in regards to this only Allah knows, but it basically means that Thawab of doing an action is subtracted.  Just to give an example for the word, you may look at this hadith http://sunnah.com/bulugh/3/37

Answer (score 4):

Some hadith's in this reference:

1] [Hadith - Bukhari 3:515]

A dog for guarding the cattle or hunting

> Allah's Apostle(P.B.U.H) said, "Whoever keeps a dog, one Qirat of the
>   reward of his good deeds is deducted daily, unless the dog is used for
>   guarding a farm or cattle." Abu Huraira (in another narration) said
>   from the Prophet, "unless it is used for guarding sheep or farms, or
>   for hunting." Narrated Abu Hazim from Abu Huraira: The Prophet  said,
>   "A dog for guarding cattle or for hunting."

2] [Hadith - Bukhari 3:515]

Angels Don't enter

> I heard Allah's Apostle(P.B.U.H) saying; "Angels (of Mercy) do not
>   enter a house wherein there is a dog or a picture of a living creature
>   (a human being or an animal)."

[Reference Link](http://muttaqun.com/dogs.html)