# Are there exceptions to owning dogs as House Pets in Islam?

Tags: sharia, dogs

My 8yr old son would really like a pet and he wants to get a dog, he told me 'it is only a small one and it is quite a clean breed' but  I told him that dogs as house pets in Islam is haram But he still really would like one. My question is if there's any exceptions to having a dog a house pet considering its small, clean and doesn't leave fur everywhere?

Comment: You can look some information here [Why are dogs considered Haram in Islam?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/4137/why-are-dogs-considered-haram-in-islam?rq=1)

Comment: I think this one might actually depend on madhhab and isn't as clear cut as is often assumed; if I remember correctly, the malikis are the most liberal with dogs.

Answer (score -2):

Categorical impermissibility of pet dogs inside the house. Dogs may, however, be kept outside the main house as guards or hunting dogs etc. In your son's case, an alternate (permissible) pet may be suggested/introduced.

Comment: Please do not post your website alongside your answer as it is considered spamming. I have suggested an edit to have it removed from your answers, please avoid posting your website any more or you are at risk of being flagged as spam. See [How not to be a spammer](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)